# linking a document to another document

Tags: lookup-column, document-set, document-id

our setup for document library as follows. We have bunch of document sets (200 doc sets to be exact) in a document library. Each doc set is for particular vendor. We place contracts in each document set. Now when it comes to renew or amendment or work order we need to be able to tie to the main contract type.

I enable SP doc id. I created a lookup column that will look inside this library and show all the items.

***But I need to be able to filter this list. I only want to show the items in the given document set (instead of showing all the items from the document library). Also, I need to be able to show (ID - Title) in the drop down. Just showing ID in the drop down user wont know what item it's tie to.***

Hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) project I used to solve something similar: [Lookup Field with Picker 2010](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/44989)

> Features
>
> - Single- and multi-Selection Mode
> - Cross site picking
> - Search in picker dialog
> - Search Operators: equals, not equal, contains, begins with, greater
>     than, greater or equal than, less than, less or equal than.
> - Select fields you would like to search for.
> - Relationship behaviors
> - Supports default values (constants, current user id and default
>     values by url param, useful for 1-n scenarios) must be configured via
>     PowerShell
> - Languages: English, German
> - Delivered as SharePoint Solution Package (WSP)

Comment: Lookup with Picker works. However, 3rd party (like SP Boost or Knowledgelake or Nintex) are not recognizing this custom filed. Now what?